# why this images are getting small, i want images to be full width as its relative div(card) and to be overflow on right side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want that these images should cover the div (card) and overflow towards the right side, but I am not getting why these images are getting adjusted even if I had given images their width and height.

please help me in this matter.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
    display:flex;
}

.card img {
    width: 90%;
    height: 700px;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styler.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">

        <img class="slider" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634443-44adaa06623a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=625&q=80" alt="">
        <img class="slider" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634443-44adaa06623a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=625&q=80" alt="">
        <img class="slider" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634443-44adaa06623a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=625&q=80" alt=""> v>

    </div>
</body>
<script>
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: probably because of display: flex

Comment: the default value for flex container is flex-direction:row; if you want to change use flex-direction:column. I'll suggest to read [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this CSS...

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.card img {
    min-width: 90%;
    height: 700px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your images to cover the entire width of the parent div container, simply add the following to your .card img{} class:

```
.card img {
position: absolute;
width: 90%;
height: 700px;
```

}

This way, they are not positioned and sized according to page flow but to parent div instead.

Comment: Using position absolute isn't the right solution

Comment: and i aslo want reset of the image to overflow towards right side